# Removing public from laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am working on laravel 5.4 project.I want to remove public word from url I followed this link https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-remove-public-from-url-using-htaccess to remove public.
These steps removed the public word from xampp server but not working on live server.

Comment: could you provide us with samples of your own code?

Comment: which code part do you want to see??

Answer (score 0):

In root folder make .htaccess file with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```